# use geth in ropsten network invalid transaction v, r, s values

Tags: go-ethereum

when I use solc instruction compile following code that get bin & abi:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract TestContract{
  function multilpy(uint a,uint b) public pure return (uint){
    return a*b;
  }
}
```

And when I use geth instruction following step:

```
code = smart contract bin
abi = smart contract abi
myContract = eth.contract(abi)
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0]) 
contract = myContract.new({from: eth.accounts[0], data: code, gas: 100000})
```

to post transaction in Ethereum test network that chainid and networkid is 3.

Appear invalid transaction v, r, s values in my transaction error

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please share the entire code and the specific (quoted) error raised and the line concerned.

Comment: Sorry,my question has been update again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check these issues on GitHub the solution to this is already provided in the issue

link 1   [click here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14599)

link 2   [click here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19699)

Comment: thank,i'll test tomorrow but i don't know why chainID need to change to 1337.